# Drawing inverted triangle varying base length

Tags: c, design-patterns

I am sorry if this is such a basic question, but i've been working on this problem for hours. 
The code below prints an inverted triangle based on input rows.
How can i edit this code to draw an inverted triangle based on input base LENGTH?

I.E.:

Input base length= 5

```
  ***** //five characters here
   ***
    *
```

I somehow cant come up with a formula without messing up the pattern.
this is the code im trying to edit,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rows, i, j, space;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);

    for(i=rows; i>=1; --i)
    {
        for(space=0; space < rows-i; ++space)
            printf(" ");

        for(j=i; j <= 2*i-1; ++j)
            printf("*");

        for(j=0; j < i-1; ++j)
            printf("*");

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which give me output

input rows= 5

```
 ********* // 5 ROWS of characters
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```

thank you!

Comment: Not clear. You want the output shown or a classic triangle with the base on the last line?

Comment: If you know the number of stars of the base row, you can calculate it for any. Here I'm guessing you subtract 2 stars at every row, so the formula is easy to do.

Comment: `#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int baselength=1, i, j, space;



    printf("base length");
    scanf("%d",&baselength);


    for(i=baselength; i>=1; --i)
    {
        for(space=0; space < baselength-i; ++space)
            printf(" ");

        for(j=i; j <=2*i-1; ++j)
            printf(" *");




        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
` latest edit, almost there but i would like the spaces in between the * to be gone.

Comment: @belle then dont call `printf(" ")`? Or `printf(" *")` but `printf("*")`?

Comment: @Fl.pf. if i remove it the output is only half an inverted triangle.

Comment: @LPs output shown! thnx

Comment: @michal i have factored in already, but unsure how baselength can be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can print the rows using your program, you could derive a small formula to convert the base length to the the number of rows as follows =>

**TL;DR:**

Use the following formula:

```
BaseLength = (2 * NumberOfRows ) -1
```

**Long Version:**

First we see that with every row, the base length is always an odd number. Additionally with the addition of every row, the base length forms an Arithmetic Progression (AP) with a difference of 2, e.g. If number of rows is 2, then the base length is 3. If number of rows is 3, then the base length is 5.

As you can see, the row count forms an AP with difference 1 =>

```
1, 2, 3, 4, ...
```

Correspondingly, the base length forms the AP with difference 2 =>

```
1, 3, 5, 7 ...
```

Therefore, we can calculate the n(th) element in the base length AP as follows =>

```
T(n) = a + (n - 1)*d
```

Where `a` is the first element in the series, and `d` is the difference between the elements in the series. Plug in the values `a = 1`, `d = 2`

```
T(n) = 1 + (n - 1)*2 = 2n -1
```

Notice here, that `n` represents the number of rows, `T(n)` represents the base length, implying that the relation becomes =>

```
BaseLength = (2 * NumberOfRows ) -1
```

Therefore, if you input `BaseLength = 9`, you get `NumberOfRows = 5`.

You can use this formula in your code to convert the base length to number of rows, whilst keeping the core functionality (i.e. printing rows of *) exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: its interesting to note that an even number of baselength would give me half a row. if considered, would i have to nest an entirely new loop in? with new formula

Comment: rows = ( baselength +2)/2 * 
apologises for multiple comments.

Comment: just realised even cant give symmetrical triangles.

Comment: For even base length, you could try using "ciel() : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/" or "floor() : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/ " functions to round up the decimal values to integers.

Comment: However, with even base length, I'm not sure if you'll get the visually aesthetic * triangle :)